# How do I use iptables to modify SRC based on DST PORT and also modify DST PORT

Tags: iptables

I have an interesting problem.

I have a client machine IP 10.10.10.55 that needs to connect to a server machine IP 10.10.10.5
They are both windows machines, and they both go through a gateway linux machine at IP 10.10.10.111

The client makes many requests to the server, and for testing purposes I want the server to think many different IP are accessing it.

So I thought to use iptables to simulate many Source IPs from the client.

I made a table like this:

```
PORT | IP
1020 | 10.10.10.20
1021 | 10.10.10.21
... etc ...
```

And then I sent connections to the server at different ports so that the iptables on the gateway will modify them.

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp --dport 1020 -j SNAT --to-source 10.10.10.20
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp --dport 1021 -j SNAT --to-source 10.10.10.21
... etc ...
```

Now, the problem is that I actually need to access the server only through port 1418.
This means I also have to modify the destination port. But that has to happen in PREROUTING which means I won't be able to catch the port in POSTROUTING.

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 10.10.10.5 -p tcp -j DNAT --to-destination 10.10.10.5:1418
```

So, I am stumped here.

How can I use the iptables to get my desired outcome? I thought of doing some kind of loopback. Where I modify the destination address in prerouting to come back into the gateway, and to change the source address. And then when it comes in the second time it would change the destination address/port again.

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -s 10.10.10.55 -d 10.10.10.5 -p tcp -j DNAT --to-destination 10.10.10.111
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp --dport 1020 -j SNAT --to-source 10.10.10.20

iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -s 10.10.10.20 -d 10.10.10.111 -p tcp -j DNAT --to-destination 10.10.10.5:1418
```

But this just doesn't work. I am sure this must be possible somehow. Thanks for help.

Output from `iptables -L -v -n` (as the tag requested) :

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

Comment: Machines in same subnet do not talk via gateway but directly. Assign and configure several ip addresses (from your subnet) on the client machine and make a test client that randomly binds to one of them when sending requests.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution using the MARK option.

For each of the ports I make a rule like this:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -s 10.10.10.55 -d 10.10.10.5 -p tcp --dport 1020 -j MARK --set-mark 1020
```

And one like this:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -m mark --mark 1020 -j SNAT --to-source 10.10.10.20
```

And I also have this rule that overrides the destination so that it will always get to where it needs to go.

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -s 10.10.10.55 -d 10.10.10.5 -p tcp -j DNAT --to-destination 10.10.10.5:1418
```

I also needed to make a rule to make sure that the responses got back as well!

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 10.10.10.20 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.10.10.55
```

And that is pretty much it!